# How to solve the release pipeline deployment issue with the artifacts?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

I'm using Azure DevOps REST API to create the release pipeline and deploy through programatically. After triggering the deploy API it starts the release but it unable to download the artifacts. In the artifact section, I've configured Azure Repos to download the code within the agent. I'm getting the following error.

> [Error 1]
>       TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier 21 does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are
>   attempting.

The number 21 is the times I have tried to accomplish this task. I don't know what went wrong.

For creating the release, I'm using the following details in the request body.

```
"definitionId": String(release_definition_id),
"artifacts": [{
     "alias": releaseAlias,
     "instanceReference": {
         "definitionId": release_definition_id,
         "id": buildId,
         "sourceRepositoryId": azureRepoId,
         "sourceRepositoryType": "TfsGit",
         "sourceBranch": "master",
         "sourceVersion": azureRepoCommitId
      }
 }]
```

While creating the release it is not pointing to the correct repository id. But I have provided all the correct details in the release definition.

Comment: Can you share the whole json/script?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk This is the complete request body for creating the release. Am I missing any config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below format:

```
{
  "definitionId": 11,
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "_BSC",
      "instanceReference": {
        "sourceBranch": "master",
        "sourceRepositoryId": "ee63d8d0-xxx-0bc08b6712be",
        "sourceRepositoryType": "TfsGit",
        "id": "34a0883b8c-xxxxx-b46c03958b0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**Key Points** on above definition:

**`alias`**: As you described, you set the `Azure Repos` in artifact section. Here this alias value should be the one of your `repos alias`. For example, my repo name is `BSC`, so my repos alias is `_BSC`.

**`id`**: Change the `sourceVersion` of your definition to `id`. Then put `commit id` here.

Comment: Thanks @Merlin Liang - MSFT. I'm following this official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#buildversion

Comment: In the official documentation, they mentioned to provide the `buildId`value for `id` property. After your answer, I got it clear and replaced with my commit id. It is working as expected.

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS. The doc seems give the confusing direction here. Share you my experience on such api configured. Just do the same action from UI, then check api records from F12. It never leads you wrong, hah:-) But anyway, awesome to know it work fine now.